# checkbox logic not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following form, with several checkboxes. Each set of checkboxes works fine, but when you change an input in the other set of checkboxes, it no longer filters based on the first set (and vice versa).

I need the logic from each set to crossover, and not sure how to achieve that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#type :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#type :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
  $("#fee :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#fee :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
});
var repayment = function() {

};
window.onload = function() {
  document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = function() {
    $('#years').html(this.value + ' years');
  };
  makeSomething();
};

function makeSomething() {
  $('tbody tr').each(function(idx, row) {
    var $row = $(row);
    var initialRateCell = $row.find('td')[2];
    var repaymentCell = $row.find('td').last()
    var rate = parseFloat($(initialRateCell).html());
    var repaymentVal = computeRepayment(rate);
    $(repaymentCell).html(repaymentVal.repayment);
  });
}
$("#myForm :input").change(function() {
  makeSomething();
});

function computeRepayment(rate) {
  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(rate * 100, 10) / 120000;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
  var h = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.value, 10);

  var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

  var loantovalue = x / h * 100;

  var year = z / 12;
  return {
    repayment: repayment.toFixed(2),
    loantovalue: loantovalue,
    year: year
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="type">
  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" />2yr Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" />3yr Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t5" id="t5" />5yr Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t9" id="t9" />Tracker
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t1" id="t1" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<section id="fee">
  <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f2" id="f2" />Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f3" id="f3" />No Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f1" id="f1" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<form name="repaymentcalc" id="myForm" action="">
  </br>
  <p>
    Home Value £
    <input type="number" id="homevalue" value="250000" style="width: 75px">
  </p>

  <p>
    Loan Amount £
    <input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" style="width: 75px">
  </p>

  Term
  <input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" style="width: 100px">

  <div id="years" style="display:inline-block;">25 years</div>

  <p>

    <div id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</div>

    </div>
</form>

<br>

<div id="mortgagediv">
  <table id="mortgagetable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="productheader">
        <th class="lender">Lender</th>
        <th class="type">Type</th>
        <th class="inititalrate">Initial Rate (%)</th>
        <th class="svr">SVR (%)</th>
        <th class="apr">Overall APR (%)</th>
        <th class="fee">Fee (£)</th>
        <th class="ltv">LTV (%)</th>
        <th class="repayment">Monthly Repayment (£)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t2">2yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t3">3yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t5">5yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t9">Tracker</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t2">2yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t3">3yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t5">5yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t9">Tracker</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This can't really work: `#type :checkbox:checked`, I think you want `#type [type='checkbox']:checked`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it just stops the second set of checkboxes working?

Answer (score 1):

I combined the logic of the two sets into a single callback. It is neither elegant nor efficient, but works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":checkbox").click(function() {
        $("td").parent().hide();
        var selections = [];
        $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
          selections.push("."+$(this).val());
        });
        $(".product").each(function() {
            showRow = true;
            for(i=0; i<selections.length; i++){
                if (!$(this).children(selections[i]).length){
                    showRow = false;
                }
            }
            if (showRow) $(this).show();
        });
    });
  });
```

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/te5a1gy3/) of it.

Comment: Cool, well done. An SO snippet would have been nicer than a fiddle, but okay.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try a snippet next time!

Answer (score 0):

You have the event handler on the *myform* area only

```
$("#myForm :input").change(function() {
  makeSomething();
});
```

But sections *fee* and *type* are outside the form and their change events are never cauth. So, you will need to either move the sections *type* and *fee* inside the form *myform* so they are selected within $("#myForm :input") or add another event handler for the checkboxes.

```
$("#fee :checkbox").change(function() {
    makeSomething();
});

$("#type :checkbox").change(function() {
    makeSomething();
});
```

Check out this fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/bocanegra_carlos/obcux0d8/

Comment: Tip for the future: SO has its own SO snippets, its the document icon with the `<>` in it - it's much nicer to have everything on this site directly than linking to a fiddle that might not be there somewhere in the future.

Comment: That's great!, i didn't know about it, thanks for the tip @somethinghere

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I think your function should go back to the drawing board when it comes to how you are reading the checkboxes. It can be massively simplified, or at least made more understandable by doing this:

```
// Store all active classes in this variable
var allActive = [];
// Run this function anytime something changes
function activateClasses(){
    // Create a string that jquery can use to search for all the children
    var activeClassesString = '.' + allActive.join(', .');
    // Instead of looking through _all_ the td elements,
    // only look through the parent and search in them.
    $('tbody tr').each(function(){
      var data = $(this);
      // instead of hiding all before, just hide when it finds
      // no children with the classes you want
      if(allActive.length && !data.find(activeClassesString).length) 
          data.hide();
      // otherwise, show
      else 
          data.show();
    });
}

// When your checkbox changes, add the value of it either to the 
// array of classes you want to sort, or remove it from the array
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var index = allActive.indexOf(value);
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if(!checked && index > -1)
       allActive = allActive.slice(index, 1);
    else if(checked && index === -1)
        allActive.push(value);
    activateClasses();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var allActive = [];
  function activateClasses(){
    var activeClassesString = '.' + allActive.join(', .');
    $('tbody tr').each(function(){
      var data = $(this);
      if(allActive.length && !data.find(activeClassesString).length) data.hide();
      else data.show();
    });
  }
  
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var index = allActive.indexOf(value);
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if(!checked && index > -1)
       allActive = allActive.slice(index, 1);
    else if(checked && index === -1)
        allActive.push(value);
    activateClasses();
  });
  
});
var repayment = function() {

};
window.onload = function() {
  document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = function() {
    $('#years').html(this.value + ' years');
  };
  makeSomething();
};

function makeSomething() {
  $('tbody tr').each(function(idx, row) {
    var $row = $(row);
    var initialRateCell = $row.find('td')[2];
    var repaymentCell = $row.find('td').last()
    var rate = parseFloat($(initialRateCell).html());
    var repaymentVal = computeRepayment(rate);
    $(repaymentCell).html(repaymentVal.repayment);
  });
}
$("#myForm :input").change(function() {
  makeSomething();
});

function computeRepayment(rate) {
  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(rate * 100, 10) / 120000;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
  var h = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.value, 10);

  var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

  var loantovalue = x / h * 100;

  var year = z / 12;
  return {
    repayment: repayment.toFixed(2),
    loantovalue: loantovalue,
    year: year
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="type">
  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" />2yr Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" />3yr Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t5" id="t5" />5yr Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t9" id="t9" />Tracker
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t1" id="t1" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<section id="fee">
  <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f2" id="f2" />Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f3" id="f3" />No Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f1" id="f1" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<form name="repaymentcalc" id="myForm" action="">
  </br>
  <p>
    Home Value £
    <input type="number" id="homevalue" value="250000" style="width: 75px">
  </p>

  <p>
    Loan Amount £
    <input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" style="width: 75px">
  </p>

  Term
  <input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" style="width: 100px">

  <div id="years" style="display:inline-block;">25 years</div>

  <p>

    <div id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</div>

    </div>
</form>

<br>

<div id="mortgagediv">
  <table id="mortgagetable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="productheader">
        <th class="lender">Lender</th>
        <th class="type">Type</th>
        <th class="inititalrate">Initial Rate (%)</th>
        <th class="svr">SVR (%)</th>
        <th class="apr">Overall APR (%)</th>
        <th class="fee">Fee (£)</th>
        <th class="ltv">LTV (%)</th>
        <th class="repayment">Monthly Repayment (£)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t2">2yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t3">3yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t5">5yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t9">Tracker</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t2">2yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t3">3yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t5">5yr Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t9">Tracker</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f2">999</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Make better use of variables as well, as your code is very heavy. For example, instead of letting jQuery compile a list of all the `td`s in your document every time, assign it to a global variable. If `td` should be added dynamically, only update this global variable when new ones are added. That means the jQuery object *already* exists and there is no time involved in recompiling it, speeding up your code. At the moment that makes little difference, but once your list becomes long enough you will feel some slowdown. I'm also very sure that classes are maybe not your best option here. Maybe `data-` attributes are better suited, so your `tr` looks like this:

```
<tr data-lender="nationwide" data-type="2-years-fixed" data-rate="1.64" data-svr="1.5" /* ... and so on ...*/ ></tr>
```

The reason you'd want to do that is because this is much more legible than your arbitrary classes - you *will* get lost in the arbitrary classes you used as they are in no way obvious. Which is more obvious: 'show me a lender with `tg-031e f1 f2`' or 'Show me a lender with 2-years-fixed type'? (I know its not correct, they aren't saying the same thing, but that's only because I am *already* getting lost in the technical terms.) Think of the developer that might come *after* you, and the headache you will be creating. Don't be afraid to use a couple more characters if it makes things more obvious to read, as it will save you a boatload of time in the long run.

Comment: I completely agree, but I just don't have the knowledge to make those changes at the moment. I will look into all your suggestions, but for now, the code snippet you have attached still does not solve the original problem, or am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Oh wait a minute, your classes are combined? You have made it _so hard_ on yourself to debug. The fact that the checkboxes have a part of a classname that has to be _in a certain order_ is what is making this so complicated. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Okay thanks! Sorry its so hard, I used code from a previous form I made, and I should have just started again! I have an issue with the `<div id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</div>` not updating aswell, can you see the problem I have with that?

Comment: I'm very sorry mate, I tried to create a database out of it (as an object) an then loop through that but I got lost again on how this is supposed to work. I think fixing this will be hard and you would save time by simply rebuilding it _but simpeler_. Very sorry, but I can't fix this without putting significant effort in - and if thats the case I might as well pop over to Stack Overflow careers and get paid for it... Good luck.

Comment: Haha fair enough! No problem, thanks for looking at it though!